Unasble to use SerialPort in a DLL
Using VB in VS2019 I am trying to develop a DLL to control a device attached to a USB connection using a virtual comms port
The code below gives a red underline to the word "SerialPort" an the error BC30002 (Type SerialPort is not defined)
Imports System.IO.Ports
Imports System.Threading
Public Class PortTest
Dim My_Port As SerialPort

Also all keywords associated with MYPORT later in the code get red underlines and the message BC30451.
The same code works vithin a form (with only the one Class statement for the form)
Also it works if the SerialPort code is in a User Control
Also I used NUGET to install the latest System.IO.SerialPort, but no change
What am I doing wrong?

Are you not doing Imports System.IO.Ports? Please refer to the examples by specifying the language dropdown list in SerialPort Class to VB.

The original post has become re-arranged. System.IO.Ports is being imported.

When I incorporated the example program introduced in the comments in Visual Studio 2022 as a project, no problem occurred. Could it be that the Visual Studio version, .NET type (Framework/Core), version, library version, etc. are not consistent? Or if you don't need Visual Studio 2019, why not try switching to Visual Studio 2022?

I have loaded the project (the code aiming at a DLL) into VS2022. The same red markimgs appear.

Maybe you tried the problem project you are asking about, rather than a new project using the example source code? How about creating a minimal project that causes the problem like these help articles and adding its source code and .vbproj file to your question? How do I ask a good question?, How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example

I have re-created a minimum example in VB202 using library class. The code entered is shown below. With just this example the word SerialPort get a red underline and the error message BC30002 (type "serialport" is undefined)  Code   Imports System.IO.Ports
Imports System.Threading
Public Class Class1
Dim my_Port As serialPort
End Class

No problem occurs when I try the same. For example, does the .vbproj configuration (such as TargetFramework type and version) not match the System.IO.Ports PackageReference or version specification, or the installed .NET SDK version is inconsistent.

Target framewrok is 8.0, but where do I find the other versions? On checking Soution Explorer for the vs2022 verion then Frameworks and Microsoft.NETCore.app I noticed that SYSTEM, and various SYSTEM.IO packages were present BUT not SYSTEM.IO.PORTS.

Please make sure that <PackageReference Include="System.IO.Ports" Version="8.0.0" /> is included in the <ItemGroup> of the .vbproj file. If it's not there, install the component using Visual Studio's NuGet package management tool.

Thank you. I used NUGET to instal the SYSTEM.IO.PORTS. I still cannot understand why the problem did not show with the form or user control versios of my code.
